# Find start & end of consecutive weekday within a list of dates in Python

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a series of dates that only contains weekdays (no weekends)

```
from datetime import datetime as dtm
df=pd.DataFrame([dtm(2022,3,1),dtm(2022,3,2),dtm(2022,3,3),dtm(2022, 4, 15),dtm(2022,4,18),dtm(2022,4,19),dtm(2022,4,20)],columns=['dates'])


dates
0   2022-03-01
1   2022-03-02
2   2022-03-03
3   2022-04-15
4   2022-04-18
5   2022-04-19
6   2022-04-20
```

I want to create a dataframe where only start and end dates of consecutive WEEKDAY dates, using the above example, the desired output is

```
    dates
0   2022-03-01
1   2022-03-03
2   2022-04-15
3   2022-04-20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for difference between days if greater like `7` with aggregate `min` and `max` datetimes, then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = (df.groupby((~df['dates'].diff().dt.days.le(7)).cumsum())['dates']
        .agg(['min','max'])
        .stack()
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
0   2022-03-01
1   2022-03-03
2   2022-04-15
3   2022-04-20
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```